# Firebase - Index rule for attributes under key created by ChildAutoById

Tags: firebase

I store my data on Firebase with the format

```
{
  "list": [
    "id created by Firebase": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    "another id created by Firebase": {
      "foo": "bar"
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to create an index on `foo`, using Firebase Rules. 
However, according to Firebase doc, I need to know the specific ID created by Firebase to put in the rules specification. 
Does anyone know of a way to get around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to know the specific ID, that wouldn't be possible. You simply need to have an `.indexOn` rule on the parent node. https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/indexing-data.html

```
{
  "rules": {
    "list": {
      ".indexOn": ["foo"]
    }
  }
}
```

If you need to add additional rules for the children, then you add those normally like so:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "list": {
      ".indexOn": ["foo"],

      "$item": {
        "foo": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString()"
        }
      }

    }
  }
}
```