# Why does this ".indexOn" not work?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase database at the console, my data under Contests/AprilMay is visualized as follows

[image]

When I export the JSON it seems like this:

```
"Contests" : {
    "AprilMay" : {
      "dummy" : 0,
      "user3" : 240,
      "user5" : 69,
      "user6" : 155
    }
  },
```

I try to index on value. My question seems similar to the one in thread:

[Why does this Firebase ".indexOn" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860141/why-does-this-firebase-indexon-not-work)

But, my rules does not work:

```
{
 "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true,
    "Contests" : {
      "AprilMay" : {
        ".indexOn" : ".value"     
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

When I set the query using OrderByValue() in my client code (Unity), it works well. But I want to order it by rules for the sake of performance.
When I use this without any rule definition:

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Contests/AprilMay")
                .OrderByValue().ValueChanged += HandleLeaderBoardChanged
```

When I define rules in the console, I erase the OrderByValue() part (shouldn't I?)

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Contests/AprilMay")
                .ValueChanged += HandleLeaderBoardChanged
```

But it does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does this Firebase ".indexOn" not work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860141/why-does-this-firebase-indexon-not-work)

Comment: The answer to the question linked in your question is the correct answer for your question as well. Also, it's unclear what *it does not work* means in this context; what isn't working? Is there an error?

Comment: The additional question about OrderByValue() is unclear. OrderByValue() is not a valid rule or part of rules at all (rules don't do ordering) so it would not be included. If you remove it from your observe/query, the resultant data will not be ordered.