# Annoying issue regarding indexOn in Firebase rules

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have read practically every StackOverflow answer and none of them worked for my scenario since this is a frequent issue. My Xcode console is giving a very common warning when querying for data in Firebase. That warning is `Using an unspecified index. Your data will be downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "username" at /users to your security rules for better performance`

What I have tried was to first read the Firebase documentation understanding exactly what I am doing along with other answers as stated such as [Why does this Firebase ".indexOn" not work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32860141/why-does-this-firebase-indexon-not-work?rq=1). Below, I have provided my security rules doing exactly as the message prompt; adding indexOn at /users but to no success. I have also provided my database users node and one function below.

```
{
  "rules": {
     ".read": true,
     ".write": true,
    "users":{
             ".indexOn": "username"
             }
         }
     }
```

My Firebase database at /users in JSON format

```
    "users":{
      "5LYUynelLTcL8Bg9WNWGXV34YIq2" {
         "email": "user1@gmail.com"
         "username": "user1"
         }
       "9srk307kzxOW7j6dNmMaac9eYPu2" {
         "email": "user2@gmail.com"
         "username": "user2"
     }
```

My function that I use in Swift

```swift
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: passedInFriendString)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        print(snapshot)
        }
```

I'm not sure where else to turn to. Any insight on if this is even the correct format to query for what I want would be great!

Comment: Hey Paul. That index definition looks fine to me for the code that you shared. Are you certain you added it to the project you're querying, and that you saved the rules and gave it a moment to propagate?

Comment: Sure did Frank. I’m glad you answered. I’ve tried doing it with one of your other solutions going one level deeper but with $user_ID. I’m not sure what is wrong. Is it my configuration?

Comment: As said: the index definition looks fine for the code you shared. There's not a lot more I can think of, beyond something like it being a different project.

Comment: Yeah I’m baffled. Should I modify the way I’m querying by any chance? I’m using some variable that holds a string to check but I wasn’t sure. It’s just strange

Comment: Frank, I realized that I can print the snapshot but I cannot do something like ``if snapshot.hasChild``. Is there some reason as to why I can't modify what I want to return? I can print the snapshot though which I didn't realize. I have tons of functions returning Firebase data but I also assumed that the simple function above would not execute. However, I cannot do anything else though which is really bothersome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it!

The thing I did not realize was that the above code in my question DOES print the snapshot successfully after adding the appropriate index definition on /users. My issue was realizing you need to loop through the snapshot if you want to further access data of the username snapshot I was querying for accordingly. That would look something like this

```
let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").queryOrdered(byChild: "username").queryEqual(toValue: passedInFriendString)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
    for child in snapshot.children {
      guard let snap = child as? DataSnapshot else {return}
      if snap.hasChild("email") {
         print("It has an email")
            }
          }
        }
```

Thanks to Frank above for guiding me and confirming that I was on the right track. I'm happy to have learned something new and super efficient whenever I need to grab data.